# Deep first search in java

Tags: java, algorithm

i m currently having problem about using Deep first search algorithm. The scenario is that user has a friend list. And it is only possible to send a message if the receiver is a friend of yours or a friends friends friends friend etc.. then you can send the message. Kinda like in facebook i guess.
what i did so far :

```
public boolean sendMessage(Message message, User receiver) {
        Stack s = new Stack();
        if(this.getFriends().size() > 0 ){
            return false;
        }else if(this.getFriends().contains(receiver)){
            receiver.getMessagebox().add(message);
            this.getMessagebox().add(message);
            return true;
        }else if(checkFriendsCircle(receiver,this,s)){
            receiver.getMessagebox().add(message);
            this.getMessagebox().add(message);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }


private boolean checkFriendsCircle(User receiver, User user, Stack s){

        ArrayList<User> friendslist = user.getFriends();
        if(!s.contains(this)){
        s.push(this);
        }
        for (User user2 : friendslist) {
            if(!s.contains(user2)){
            if(user2.getFriends().contains(receiver)){
                return true;
            }else{
                checkFriendsCircle(receiver,user2,s);

            }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? And btw I think it might be that in line 3 You want to check for `.size() <= 0`...

Comment: well it is not working. Thats my problem :)

Comment: by the way thanks ! i totally missed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be with the method `checkFriendsCircle`. The recursive call is `checkFriendsCircle(user,user2.getFriends(),s);` instead of `checkFriendsCircle(user2,user2.getFriends(),s);`. You actually don't check more than one level of friendship.

Comment: user is the receiver , so every time in the recursive call i m need to send the receiver to see if its there

Comment: ... and maybe a `return` in front of `checkFriendsCircle(...)` could help.

Comment: sorry i corrected the code. Still got the same problem though

Comment: every time i need to send the receiver so i can see if he is on someones list

Comment: while looping on the list of friends, you loop on the list friendslist instead of friendsList which you got in the recursive call.

Comment: ok i corrected that so every time i m sending checkFriendsCircle(receiver,user,s);
so the reciver who we are looking for and the user is changing every time through the loop.. but still not working